# InvalidArgumentException shows when i try to add a user?

Tags: laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2.
When i am try to add a new user with password and confirm password, it shows an InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 589:Action App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CreateEmployeeController@save-employee not defined.
The error comes when i added the passwordconfirm function.
The passwordconfirm function is used to validate password and confirm password at the time of user creation.
        //Route:
    Route::post('save-employee','CreateEmployeeController@passwordconfirm');

```
//controller

 public function passwordconfirm(Request $request)

                  {

                      $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [

                          'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',

                          'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:6',

                      ]);

                      if ($validator->fails())

                       {

                          return redirect('admin\create-employee')
                                      ->withErrors($validator)
                                      ->withInput();

                      }
                      else
                      {

                          return Redirect::action('Admin\CreateEmployeeController@save-employee');

                   }



                    }
```

Comment: Your error interest  function CreateEmployeeController@save-employee can you post It?

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check your routes if redirect function of controller exist and is correct.
2. Try to use return redirect()->action('Admin\CreateEmployeeController@save-employee');
3. Otherwise read redirect route in the documentation laravel https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirecting-controller-actions you can execute a function calling the route and pass parameters if you want.